# How to detect which key was pressed in SDL2 without repetitive cases?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I need to create an input box in a SDL window.

Since there is no function for that I am going to make a basic input box, but I can't find how to detect which key is pressed in SDL.

With this code below, I can print when I hit `'A'` but i think making this for each character will be really repetitive. How can I detect which key is pressed?

```
case: SDL_KEYDOWN:
    switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
        case SDLK_a:
            cout << "You Clicked \'A\'" << endl;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`SDL_Keysym::sym`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keysym) is an [`SDL_Keycode`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keycode) value. As you can see in the [lookup table](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDLKeycodeLookup), these keycodes just correspond to ASCII values where possible. Checking if it's between `0x20` and `0x7f` (inclusive) should be a decent way to detect that.

You can also use [`SDL_GetKeyName`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyName) to get the name of the key as a string.

Note that modifiers like Shift are not taken into account. I assume that's okay because you asked for detecting key presses, not typed characters. Otherwise, [`SDL_TextInputEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_TextInputEvent) is probably closer to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753335/10871073) is great but I figured I would add some code to illustrate what it means for future visitors.

You can either save or cast the `SDL_Keysym::sym` to a `char` to output the corresponding text:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent)) { 
    if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym >= 33 && sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym <= 126) { // Printable keys are 33 - 126
        std::cout << (char)sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym;
    }
}
```